# Is `use_frameworks!` necessary when using a pod which uses swift internally, but publically is obj-c?

Tags: cocoapods

Is there any way I can make a pod which uses swift internally (private) and does not require users of the library to have `use_frameworks!` enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your library contains Swift at all, it is required to be bundled in a framework. This is because Swift cannot be distributed in static libraries, regardless of whether it's public or private.